# How to find a shared library file, if it is in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I know name of the library (no root access)?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, links

Suppose I have a program that depends on `libbz2`. The `libbz2.so.1` file is in the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and I can compile with `-lbz2` without a problem.

How can I find the particular shared object file used for compilation?

A standard way to this is to use `ldconfig` (like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282199/find-out-if-library-is-in-path), for instance). However, `ldconfig` requires root, at least on Debian, and I want to look for the file from an unprivileged bash script.

So the question is, how do find a specific file used *without* root access? Given that gcc has no issue finding the library, it seems very much possible.

**Edit**: I seem to have formulated my initial question poorly. I want to know what file the linker would use if I were to compile the program, *without actually compiling it*.

Comment: Have a look at `ldd`.

Comment: I want to find the file before compilation.

Comment: You mean, you want to find the file that `gcc` would use, given the supplied options? Please clarify your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925012/can-i-get-a-report-of-all-the-libraries-linked-when-building-my-c-executable

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have added a clarification to the initial question.

Comment: I'd assume that `gcc` (or `ld`, or whatever) looks at `/etc/ld.so.conf` and the options it got, and then searches for candidates. Difficult to find that out without actually doing it, you'd have to rip out the corresponding code out of `gcc`, and run it as your own program ... which doesn't make sense when you can just run `gcc`.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. It's just that `ldconfig` can do that stuff, it seems pretty useful, and it is strange that looking up what file -lbz2 resolves to is bundled with root-level actions. Was hoping there was a separate utility, or an option I didn't know.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Quote from manpage: `ldconfig` **creates** the necessary links  and  cache  to  the  most  recent shared  libraries  found  in  the  directories specified on the command line [and others detailed there]. That's why it needs root (to **create** the links). **gcc** may have additional strategies for searching (e.g. when cross-compiling). They are not the same. **Why** do you need to find a particular library, if you are not going to link to it? I don't think anybody ever had this use case, and hence there's no extra utility for it.